# Fire Salesforce Trigger only once?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have a managed package which has a visual force page which is used for expense submittion. The purpose of this page is so someone can submit multiple expenses at the same time (with several rows listed) against different projects.

When the user submits the expense, in the background it creates the following:

1. An expense line item for each expense
2. An expense 'Report' which is basically a parent to the expense item, there is one created for each Project and if its Billable/Non Billable for a project. Thats what defines the 'Expense Report' - those expenses are then linked to it.

Now, from a financial perspective, I am trying to Group these expense reports as a 'Expense Claim' so the user can see one figure for each lot of expenses they submitted.

The problem I have, is that I created a Trigger on the 'Expense Report' object to create a record in a custom 'Claim' object, and then I loop through the Expense Reports to link them to the claim. That was the idea.

However, obviously, if there are 4 Expense Reports being created, the trigger will run 4 times. I want this to only run once and loop through all the Expense Reports to update them with the Expense Claim ID I created.

I cannot find any unique identifier to identify that these were all submitted at the same time. I could use something like the User and CreatedDate but I don't think this is a very reliable way of doing it? perhaps I am wrong.

Need to remember there could be multiple people submitting these at any one time, so not sure I can go down the route of a Utility Class.

Does anyone have any idea's? Unfortunately as its a managed package, I cannot put my own field on this Expense Visual force page.

I would post my code so far but not sure it will be a lot of use. Just open to suggestions really!

Thanks

Comment: You need to bulkify your trigger

Comment: Have a look at avoid recursive trigger https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000133752&language=en_US&type=1